# How to represent an anonymous function as a string

Tags: string, casting, type-conversion, julia, anonymous-function

I want to represent a function like x->x^2 as a string - simply doing string(x->x^2) doesn't work, is there any way around this?

Comment: Can't you use something like `str = string(:x, :->, :(x^2))`? Then you can do `fun = eval(parse(str))` and then execute `fun(2)`.

Comment: If you want to create dynamic anonymous functions at run-time, one possibility is to pass it's `Expr` equivalent, by this way the string to `Expr` parsing time will be saved.

Comment: another question would be: why do you need this? Maybe there is a way to do what you need differently?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function from string using `fun=eval(parse("x->x^2"))` but as far as I know it's an irreversible process.

Comment: Well I can't change the API - I have to pass an anonymous function, so that's out of the question. It's weird though there is no option to do so, time for some improvements I guess.

Comment: Decoding a compiled source into it's original text string is not a straightforward job, and even if a decoder do this, mostly, the generated text wont be exactly the same as the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something works, doesn't mean it is a solution... Suppose `f` is the anonymous function. With `f = x->x^2`. Then the following:

```
join(map(strip,match(r"line \d*:\n(.*)\n",string(f.code)).captures),"\n")
```

Gives:

```
return x ^ 2
```

More can be extracted using regular expressions from `f.code`. Also note this doesn't work for non-anonymous functions. And it isn't something one should rely on to work. Perhaps some other way to implement the functionality would be best.